# Unable to query database using the values in array using linq

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, .net, linq-to-sql

I have two tables. Post table and Follow table. Post table has all the posts of a user and Follow table has the list of user followed by a user.

**Post Table**

```
PostID    UserID      Post
1            2       TextOne
2            1       TextTwo
3            1       Text3
4            2       Text4
```

**Follow Table**

```
ID     Following        FollowedBy
1        2                  1
2        3                  1
```

And I have a list view.

```
<ItemTemplate >       
    Post:
    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Post") %>' />
    <br />
    UserID:
    <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("UserID") %>' />
    <br />          
 </ItemTemplate>
```

I want to show the posts of the user and the people who he are following. I wrote the following code.

```
int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User"]);
int[] OthersPosts = (from s in Data.Follow where s.FollowedBy == UserId) select s.Following1).ToArray();

foreach (int post in OthersPosts)
{
    var DisplayPost = (from s in Data.Posts where s.UserID == post && s.UserID == UserId) select s).ToList();
    ListViewPostTable.DataSourceID = "";
    ListViewPostTable.DataSource = DisplayPost;
    ListViewPostTable.DataBind();
}
```

But no data is displayed on the `ListView`?

I have checked the watch window for the value in `DisplayPost` variable, it says `Enumeration yielded no results`.

Comment: Whats the return value in OthersPosts array ?

Comment: The user id's of the persons followed by 'UserId'

Comment: i thinks you have correct the query may be like this:
var DisplayPost = (from s in Data.Posts where s.PostID == post && s.UserID == UserId) select s).ToList();

Comment: but the OtherPosts array is array of UserId ,how can i search in PostID ? i just named it post but it is user

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is in the following predicate:

```
s.UserID == post && s.UserID == UserId
```

Since `UserID` is always different from `post` which is one of the users he is following, this predicate always returns `false`.

You should at least change it to

```
s.UserID == post || s.UserID == UserId
```

I.e. you want to find posts by the user himself or one of the users he's following.

This still won't work as expected if he's following more than one user because in the `foreach` loop you'll be binding data to `ListViewPostTable` multiple times. Of course at the end you'll only see the last result.

Try replacing the `foreach` loop like this:

```
var DisplayPost = (
    from s in Data.Posts 
    where s.UserID == UserId || OthersPosts.Contains(s.UserID)
    select s).ToList();
ListViewPostTable.DataSourceID = "";
ListViewPostTable.DataSource = DisplayPost;
ListViewPostTable.DataBind();
```

Comment: + 1 for using `Contains`, instead of `foreach`.

Comment: @GeneliaD'Souza you would want to remove the `s.UserID == UserId ||` from the `where` clause as it would load the `Session["User"]`'s posts as well. Which not what you want, I guess.

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi i want that too

Answer (score 0):

Change your code like this.

```
int UserId = Convert.ToInt32(Session["User"]);
int[] OthersPosts = (from s in Data.Follow where s.FollowedBy == UserId) select s.Following1).ToArray();

List<Posts> lstPosts = new List<Posts>();

foreach (int post in OthersPosts)
{
    var displayPost = (from s in Data.Posts where s.UserID == post) select s).ToList();
    lstPosts.AddRange(displayPost);
}

ListViewPostTable.DataSourceID = "";
ListViewPostTable.DataSource = lstPosts;
ListViewPostTable.DataBind();
```

You were matching the `s.UserID == post && s.UserID == UserId`. Which is wrong, because a post will not belong to two users.

Comment: Following and FollowedBy are the user Id's of the user in follow table, in the query "int[] OthersPosts = (from s in Data.Follow where s.FollowedBy == UserId) select s.Following1).ToArray();" how can i load Person that iam following into the array 'OthersPost' and search for 'PostId' ? and still it is not working i think it is wrong

Comment: OthersPost is loading UserId's

Comment: Yes, it would load `UserID`s. And in the `foreach` loop you would get their posts.

Comment: but how to display posts of all users that a user follows ?

Comment: See the edited answer. The `foreach` loop would fetch of all the posts from users who are being followed by the `Session["User"]`. And those posts would be added to the `List` variable `lstPosts`. Finally after getting all posts from all users, `lstPosts` would be assigned to `ListViewPostTable.DataSource`.